# SQL Server with C# in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2015

```
public DataTable getData(string procedureName, SqlParameter[] procedureParams)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = procedureName;
    command.Connection = connection;

    if (procedureParams != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < procedureParams.Length; i++)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(procedureParams[i]);
        }
    }

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(table);   

    return table;
}
```

On the line

```
adapter.Fill(table);
```

I get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

What's the problem? I'm doing c# inventory management system on Visual Studio and I'm struggling with this part of class db class

Comment: Show the complete error message not only it's type

Comment: Please explain your problem properly .

Comment: Add a `try-catch` block at least and catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your connection is open before you can fill the datatable. The code can also be slightly consolidated.

```
public DataTable getData(string procedureName, SqlParameter[] procedureParams)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(procedureName, connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    if (procedureParams != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < procedureParams.Length; i++)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(procedureParams[i]);
        }
    }

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)        
        connection.Open();

    adapter.Fill(table);  
    connection.Close(); 

    return table;
}
```

Also, note that you are not setting the timeout property of your command object, so it will use the default.  That can be set as part of the command if needed.

```
    command.CommandTimeout = my_timeout_variable;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are doing wrong while filling DataTable, you shouldn't fill DataTable, instead you should fill DataSet. Try doing this

```
        public DataTable getData(string procedureName, SqlParameter[] procedureParams)
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = procedureName;
            command.Connection = connection;
            if (procedureParams != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < procedureParams.Length; i++)
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(procedureParams[i]);
                }
            }

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds); //Fill DataSet and try accessing your table from DataSet
            return ds.Tables[0];
        }
```

Comment: If you only need a single table, you can definitely fill a `DataTable` directly, instead of having a bloated `DataSet` and then grabbing the one and only `.Tables[0]` from it.....

Comment: @marc_s Thanks !!

Comment: Can you please put all code try catch block and let me know the actual exception